# Ajax + Spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Есть jsp-страница со скриптом

```
<form id="mail_send">
    Name <input type="text" id="inp1">
    <input type="button" value="send" id="butt1">
    <br>
    <p id="result1"></p>
    <p id="result2"></p>
</form>
```

---

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#butt1').click(function () {
               var par1=$('#inp1').val();
               $.ajax({
                   type:'POST',//тип запроса
                   data:{param1:par1},//параметры запроса
                   url:"<c:url value="mvcmethod"/> ",//url адрес обработчика
                   success: funcSuccess//возвращаемый результат от сервера
               });
           });
        });
        function funcSuccess() {

        }
    </script>
```

Есть контроллер

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mvcmethod", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void mvcmethod(Model model,
                          @RequestParam(value = "param1")String param){
        model.addAttribute("attr1", param);
        model.addAttribute("attr2", "hello");
    }
```

Со страницы на контроллер получаю `param1`, а вернуть с контроллера хочу два параметра: `attr1`, `attr2`. Вопрос: как их(значения) правильно отправить с контроллера на страницу и словить в ajax-скрипте? И еще, где правильно, на странице писать скрипты, в боди или в хэде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указываешь контроллеру обязательно аннотацию `@ResponseBody`
Вот как возвращать Model в виде json можешь глянуть где нить(я не пробовал), но ModelAndView знаю может возвращать, если создать так `new ModelAndView(new MappingJackson2JsonView())`  и добавлять `modelAndView.addObject(a, b);`. Бывало возвращал `Map<String,String>` не создавая модели.

На jsp, обрабатываешь уже пришедший json в funcSuccess. Как пример снизу

```
function funcSuccess(data) {
    $("#editId").text(data.id);        
    $("#editTitle").val(data.title);
    $("#editDescription").text(data.description);
    $("#editDate").val(data.date);
    $("select#editStatus").val(data.status);

}
```

Плюс возможно тебе понадобятся дополнительные библиотеки, чтоб отправлять json с контроллера.

По поводу размещения js. Размещай где угодно, лишь было читабельно и понятно другим.